# Core Animation: How to make a page flipping transition?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I want to create a page flipping transition for an iPhone app like the one in notes. Basically when you go to a new view the bottom or top of the page curls like if you were turning the page of a book.

Anyone know of a tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"pageCurlUp" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:someUIView cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Also look for `UIViewAnimationTransition` in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode provides a template to create an utility application, in which there is a Info button, and a flipside view. You might want to have a look at this template.

You can do the same by setting the modelTransitionStyle of the controller to UIModelTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideVewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];

controller.modelTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModelViewController: controller animated:YES];

[controller release];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for next and previous note flip animation

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        [transition setDelegate:self];
        [transition setDuration:0.5f];
        [transition setType:@"pageCurl"];
        [transition setSubtype:@"fromBottom"];
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"CurlAnim"];


     CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
                        [transition setDelegate:self];
                        [transition setDuration:0.5f];
                        [transition setType:@"pageUnCurl"];
                        [transition setSubtype:@"fromBottom"];
                        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"CurlAnim"];
```